# FireDac transaction behaving strangely

Tags: delphi, transactions, firebird, firedac

I'm using Firedac to connect to a Firebird 2.1 database in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. A TFDConnection has a TFDtransaction assigned. Both with default values. Then there's a code like that, more or less.

```
TFDtransaction.StartTransaction;

try

 .. // Select, update & insert statements in TFDQuery components created dinamically  here with default values

 TFDtransaction.Commit;

except

 TFDtransaction.Rollback;

end;
```

The problem is, sometimes (not always), when checking the values changed by this transaction (in FlameRobin, for example) I can't see the new values until I close the application (that is closing the connection too). Why is that so? How I can solve this? Is there a problem in the update options in the TFDConnection component?

Comment: First, make sure when the Commit is done for related changes. Check if your FDQuery runs in needed transaction but not in a default, global one that is commited at the end or by AutoCommit. And last, check your transaction isolation level, where you did not see the changed data.

Comment: Connect your FlameRobin as SYSDBA and check list of connections (AKA attachments) and transactions your database have opened (read `c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\doc\README.monitoring_tables.txt` - and notice you MUST start new transaction in FR before each read from monitoring tables or they won't be updated) - there is big chance your application is making more connections or transactions than you think it does. You may also try to monitor specific statements and their mapping to transactions using Firebird `Trace API` (if it existed in 2.1, maybe it was introduced in firebird 2.5)